# getJSON & Bearer token

Tags: jquery, json, getjson, bearer-token

I have a working getJSON script to output the JSON strings.
But with a Bearer Token api it dosnt work.

In my Http Header is  allready included..
authorization: Bearer Mytoken

does anyone have an idea for me?

```
    <div id = "stage" style = "background-color:#cc0;">
         STAGE
      </div>

      <input type = "button" id = "driver" value = "Load Data" />

<script>
         $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#driver").click(function(event){
               $.getJSON('https://www.myapiwithbtoken.com/result.json', function(jd) {
                  $('#stage').html('<p> Name: ' + jd.name + '</p>');
                  $('#stage').append('<p>Age : ' + jd.age+ '</p>');
                  $('#stage').append('<p> M: ' + jd.m+ '</p>');
               });
            });

         });
      </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are going to want to use another method to attach the bearer token to your headers when you make the request. With the code you provided, it doesn't seem like it would do so. Look at the $.ajax method, below is an example of making a GET request.

You can see that you get a "done" and "fail" callback method to work with...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", //GET, POST, PUT
    url: '/authenticatedService'  //the url to call
    contentType: contentType,           
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {   //Set token here
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer '+ token);
    }
}).done(function (response) {
    //Response ok. Work with the data returned
         $('#stage').html('<p> Name: ' + response.name + '</p>');
         $('#stage').append('<p>Age : ' + response.age+ '</p>');
         $('#stage').append('<p> M: ' + response.m+ '</p>');

}).fail(function (err)  {
    //Handle errors here
         $('#stage').append('<p>error with fetching results</p>');
});
```

Comment: this is useful, and I can see the console log that the data is retrieved. But how do you append the data in the table after this?

Comment: Sure, I will re-edit this answer to illustrate how to do that.